# Jest test fail, alert is not defined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I use jest for my react native project, I want to test the component which has "onPress". When click on it, alert come up.

```
<ListItem
      testID={'Contact'}
      onPress={() => alert('hello')}
/>
```

and to test it;

```
it('test onPress functionality', () => {
    window.alert = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Contact
        onPress={window.alert}
      />,
    );
    wrapper
      .findWhere(node => node.prop('testID') === 'Contact')
      .props()
      .onPress();
    expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');
  });
```

but this test gives alert error.

> > ReferenceError: alert is not defined onPress={() => alert('hello')}

please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.use react native Alert

```
import {Alert} from 'react-native';

<ListItem
      testID={'Contact'}
      onPress={() => Alert.alert('hello')}
/>
```

check documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert)

Answer (score 1):

Your test is incorrect, as you're testing for 'onPress' being the argument.

```
expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');
```

The above should work.

Comment: thanks to fix there, but the error not related with that, now I fix there still gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be fully related but I was getting the "not defined" error from eslint using react.js. My solution was to explicitly replace all instances of "alert" with "window.alert" and eslint fully accepted it